# iPhone SDK Facebook Insight

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook, ios4, facebook-insights

I was given a task to get a data of a fan page from facebook insight, that is to gather page likes, user visits etc. and then build chart according to that. Can any one provide me a starting point for that. I already the documentation but it could not give me any *helping hand*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first used fbconnect and give it a permission of read_insight, then make a function and call these queries to get your desired results.

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/
```